# Что есть нога, а что есть лапа?

Tags: употребление-слов

И еще один вопрос из той же серии. Только на сей раз меня интересует различие слов "нога" и "лапа".
Если считать, что нога — это нечто, оканчивающееся чем-то твердым (ноги у копытных), а лапа — мягкая, то почему у человека тоже ноги, а не лапы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тоже хороший вопрос.

Но Вы, боюсь, не совсем правильно противопоставления делаете. 
Надо противопоставлять прежде всего лапы и копыта. Кстати, эту систематику ввели еще творцы Ветхого Завета. "Б-г запретил есть тех, у кого лапы, и тех, у кого копыта не раздвоены". Ноги же могу быть и у тех и у других. С точки зрения этой систематики нога человека (а так же слона, обезьяны и даже бегемота) ближе к лапе.

Другими словами, лапа - это часть ноги, аналог ладони/кисти.

Бытовое же разделение на ноги и лапы возникло, видимо, позднее, когда несколько сместилось значение понятие "копыто" (ранее копытами называли вообще всякие ногти на нижних конечностях, включая человеческие), а "лапа" распространилась на всю конечность животного, лапу имеющего.

Некоторая путаница, естественно, появилась. Как выйти из этого положения - и надо ли - не знаю. Во всяком случае в спорных случаях всегда можно уточнить, о какой ноге или лапе идет речь.

//------------------------------------
По поводу Левита, вот точный текст. Где здесь утверждение, что в древнееврейском не было разделения на лапы и копыта?

4 только сих не ешьте из жующих жвачку и имеющих раздвоенные копыта: верблюда, потому что он жует жвачку, но копыта у него не раздвоены, нечист он для вас;
6 и зайца, потому что он жует жвачку, но копыта у него не раздвоены, нечист он для вас;
(Лев.11:4, 6)

Comment: "И зайца не ешьте, так как он хоть и жуёт жвачку, но копыта у него не раздвоены" - Левит Синодальный перевод,  цитирую по памяти. В древнееврейском не было разницы между ступнёй и копытами, так что приплетать сюда библию не стоит.

Comment: >В древнееврейском не было разницы между ступнёй и копытами,  
  
Источник?  

Хорошо, ограничимся славянскими переводами. Тоже - древность)))

По поводу Левита - дополнил ответ.

Строгое определение лапы - см. здесь.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0
Оно вполне мне подходит.

Comment: Вот хотя бы http://azbyka.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=3766 Синодальный перевод - это XIX век, не такая и древность.

На вопрос где, смотрите Левит 11;6 из текста выходит наличие у зайца нераздвоенных копыт.

Answer (score 2):

Если коленный сустав выражен лучше голеностопного, как правило, называют ногами (слоны, человек, копытные). Если наоборот - лапами. Т.е. если ложась на живот, животное передние конечности подкладывает под себя, то это ноги, а если перед собой - лапы. У человека в этом отношении руки вполне можно назвать лапой (в шутку так и называют), а ноги по строении больше похожи на передние конечности коровы, чем собаки или кошки, в шутку ноги и сравнивают с копытами, а не лапами.

Что касается разделения лап и копыт в Ветхом Завете, то или придётся признать, что древние евреи были идиотами, считавшими что заяц непарнокопытное жвачное ("и зайца, потому что он жует жвачку, но копыта у него не раздвоены, нечист он для вас" Лев 11;6), или признать, что  разделения между копытом и лапой в Библии не обозначено. И приплетать её сюда не имеет никакого смысла.

Comment: А я думаю, что, как сказал behemothus, это просто оттого, что копытами называли любую ногу.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, в вопросе про отличия ноги от копыта не спрашивалось, поэтому на него я и не отвечал. Чем же отличается нога от лапы у behemothus так и не нашёл, поэтому и оставил свой ответ